# Apache Ignite C#/.NET: Compute job failing, failed to deserialize job

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

I am new to Apache Ignite, and I was trying to follow the [Remote Assembly Loading example](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/net-specific/net-remote-assembly-loading#example) , but I ran into some errors.

First, I run `Apache.Ignite.exe -ConfigFileName=[file path to Apache.Ignite.exe.config]` a couple of times in the Windows console in order to start a cluster, where my **Apache.Ignite.exe.config** file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="igniteConfiguration" type="Apache.Ignite.Core.IgniteConfigurationSection, Apache.Ignite.Core" />
    </configSections>
    
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>

    <runtime>
        <gcServer enabled="true" />
    </runtime>

    <igniteConfiguration peerAssemblyLoadingMode='CurrentAppDomain' />

    <appSettings>
        <!-- Use Ignite configuration section defined above. -->
        <add key="Ignite.ConfigSectionName" value="igniteConfiguration" />
    </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Then I have a .NET console application where my **Program.cs** looks like:

```
    class HelloAction : IComputeAction
    {
        public void Invoke()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
            {
                PeerAssemblyLoadingMode = PeerAssemblyLoadingMode.CurrentAppDomain
            };

            using (var ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg))
            {
                ignite.GetCompute().Broadcast(new HelloAction());
            }
        }
    }
```

After I run my project, I run into the following **errors**:

```
[SEVERE][sys-#61][] Failure in Java callback
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Platform error:Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: Compute job has failed on remote node, examine InnerException for details.
 ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: Failed to deserialize the job [errType=BadImageFormatException, errMsg=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
 ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.JavaException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to deserialize the job [errType=BadImageFormatException, errMsg=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.callback.PlatformCallbackUtils.inLongOutLong(Native Method)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.callback.PlatformCallbackGateway.computeJobCreate(PlatformCallbackGateway.java:295)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.compute.PlatformAbstractJob.createJob(PlatformAbstractJob.java:114)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.compute.PlatformClosureJob.execute0(PlatformClosureJob.java:66)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.compute.PlatformAbstractJob.execute(PlatformAbstractJob.java:80)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:598)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:7077)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:592)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:521)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1368)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:2122)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GrSystem.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Compute job has failed on remote node, examine InnerException for details.)
 ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: Compute job has failed on remote node, examine InnerException for details.
 ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: Failed to deserialize the job [errType=BadImageFormatException, errMsg=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
 ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.JavaException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to deserialize the job [errType=BadImageFormatException, errMsg=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.callback.PlatformCallbackUtils.inLongOutLong(Native Method)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.callback.PlatformCallbackGateway.computeJobCreate(PlatformCallbackGateway.java:295)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.compute.PlatformAbstractJob.createJob(PlatformAbstractJob.java:114)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.compute.PlatformClosureJob.execute0(PlatformClosureJob.java:66)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.compute.PlatformAbstractJob.execute(PlatformAbstractJob.java:80)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:598)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:7077)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:592)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:521)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1368)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:2122)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1907)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1528)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$5300(GridIoManager.java:241)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.execute(GridIoManager.java:1421)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:55)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

I was wondering what is causing this error and how to fix this, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using .NET Core 3.x, while `Apache.Ignite.exe` is built using classic .NET Framework, so there is a compatibility issue.

Apache Ignite includes a .NET Core binary as well - `platforms/dotnet/bin/netcoreapp2.0/Apache.Ignite.dll`, you can try that instead.

However, when using peer assembly loading, I would recommend to run exactly the same framework version on all nodes. To do that, avoid using prebuilt binaries (`Apache.Ignite.exe` and `Apache.Ignite.dll`), and create a separate program that starts server nodes:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
        {
            PeerAssemblyLoadingMode = PeerAssemblyLoadingMode.CurrentAppDomain
        };

        using (var ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(-1); // Wait forever
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your suggestion - it worked, as the nodes discovered each other and I got Cluster `[hosts=1, CPUs=8, servers=2, clients=0, topVer=4, minorTopVer=1]` on both consoles. However, I am not seeing "Hello, World!" printed on any of the consoles - might you have an idea as to why?

Comment: A simple test works for me ([server](https://gist.github.com/ptupitsyn/600f84fa4fe9a09269384b21f7ee7120), [client](https://gist.github.com/ptupitsyn/a334dc85116ca537e276a752cffb00dd)). Look closer - `Hello, World` is probably lost among all the Ignite output.

Comment: I still could not find `Hello, World` in the consoles. 

However, `Hello, World` finally showed up when I started new files for both the server and client